# Is it possible to Serialize JSONArray in inside JSONArray using Model class?

Tags: android, arrays, json, serialization

I want to Serialize my JSONArray as ArrayList using GSon library, the resulting structure is JSONArray -> JSONArray -> JSONObject

```
//I have tried this,
try {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type placeOrdersListType = new 
TypeToken<List<PlaceOrderMaster>> 
() {
}.getType();
List<PlaceOrderMaster> placeOrdersTypeList = 
gson.fromJson(jsonObject
.getJSONArray(ResponseParams.RESULT).toString(), 
placeOrdersListType);
ArrayList<PlaceOrderMaster> arrayList = new ArrayList<> 
(placeOrdersTypeList);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

//and my model class is like this,
private ArrayList<ArrayList<PlaceOrders>> result;

// API Response like this
{
"status": 1,
"message": "Order Placed successfully!!!",
"result": [
    [
        {
            "orderid": "1841",
            "category_id": "8"
        },
        {
            "orderid": "1841",
            "category_id": "1"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "orderid": "1842",
            "category_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "orderid": "1842",
            "category_id": "6"
        }
    ]
]
}
```

Is it possible to Serializing the API response>? If yes then how?

Comment: Post your JSON response

Comment: I think you've got it reversed. You want to deserialize your API response. Can you post your JSON please?

Comment: I have put the JSON response in my question.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you want exactly? because I can see the outer most element as JSON object so do you want to skip directly to result array?

Comment: I want to do something like this get ArrayList directly 
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type placeOrdersListType = new TypeToken<List<PlaceOrder>>() 
    {}.getType();
    List<PlaceOrder> placeOrdersTypeList 
    = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONArray(
    ResponseParams.RESULT).toString(), placeOrdersListType);
    ArrayList<PlaceOrder> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(placeOrdersTypeList);

Comment: something we can do like this? 
ArrayList<ArrayList<PlaceOrder>> arrayList = new ArrayList ...